# how to use javascript and dom technology

Tags: javascript, dom

how to use javascript and dom technology
to get the values of p and span using div childs ??
this is the code

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function afficherTexts(){
var div = document.getElementById("test");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test">
    <p>2002</p>
    <span>Mon texte</span>
    </div>
    <input type=submit value="afficher p"  onClick="afficherTexts()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you considered using a library such as jQuery? Then you could just do e.g. `$('div#test p').html()`

Answer (score 2):

if you add an id to the p tag you can do this easily.

Modify the HTML code:

```
<div id="test">
    <p id='para'>2002</p>
    <span>Mon texte</span>
    </div>
    <input type=submit value="afficher p"  onClick="afficherTexts()"/>
```

JavaScript

```
var value = document.getElementById('para').innerHTML;
```

Comment: ...except that `p` (and `span`) elements don't have `value` properties... I think you'll want to use `.innerHTML`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
div.getElementsByTagName('tagName')[0].innerHTML;
```

Or

```
   var nodes=div.childNodes;
   var pHtml = nodes[0].innerHTML;
   var spanHtml = nodes[1].innerHTML;
```

Comment: i want to use getElementById and childs(firstChild..)

Comment: But there is no attribute `id` for `span` and `p`. And you would only get first element with `firstChild` method. Another way you can do is by using `childNodes` method.

Answer (score 0):

Using nodes as opposed to innerHTML. With nodes you can distinguish between text and elements.

```
// reference to first div
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

// reference to first p in first div
var p = div.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];

// get p text using nodes
var pText = p.childNodes[0].nodeValue;

// reference to first span in first div
var span = div.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];

// get span text
var spanText = span.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

The difference between using nodes and innerHTML is you can get just text if you so wish. Using this method you can bypass any HTML contained in a element and get raw text.

**HTML**

```
<p>
    2002
    <span>2003</span>
    2004
</p>
```

**Javascript**

```
var pText = "";

for(var i=0,l=p.childNodes.length;i<l;i++) {
    var node = p.childNodes[i];
    // if node is a text node
    if(node.nodeType===3)
        { pText += node.nodeValue.trim(); }
}

// 20022004
window.alert(pText)
```

See more on [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) and [Node.nodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType).

Answer (score 0):

This code will get the values of *every* paragraph and span in the div, stored separately:

```
var testDiv = document.getElementById('test');
var output = {};console.log(testDiv.childNodes);
for (var idx in testDiv.childNodes) {
    var child = testDiv.childNodes[idx];
    switch (child.nodeName) {
        case 'P':
            // fallthrough
        case 'SPAN':
            if (output[child.nodeName]) {
                output[child.nodeName].push(child.innerHTML);
            } else {
                output[child.nodeName] = [child.innerHTML];
            }
            break;
        default:
            // empty
            break;
    }
}

console.log(output);
```

Output:

```
v Object {P: Array[1], SPAN: Array[1]}
  v P: Array[1]
      0: "2002"
      length: 1
    > __proto__: Array[0]
  v SPAN: Array[1]
      0: "Mon texte"
      length: 1
    > __proto__: Array[0]
  > __proto__: Object
```